# element-api: include a collection with mixed entry types, and nested includes

Tags: craft3, plugin-elementapi

Does anyone know how to include a collection of entries, containing multiple entry-type, in such way that:
 1. Each entry type gets transformed by its own custom transformer class (tailord to the entry type's data structure).
 2. Nested include names get passed along  and processed by the custom entry transformers, in order to load their own supported resources.

To try and give a basic example, I am trying to setup an endpoint for a landing page entry, which includes a mixed set of featured entries, which each in turn include some extra data.

The goal is to have an endpoint such as `api/pages/my-landing-page.json?include=featured,featured.topic,featured.event` return data similar to:

```
[
  "id" => 12,
  "type" => "landingPage",
  "postDate" => "2019-05-08T12h30",
   ...
  "featured" => [
     // loaded in `LandingPageTransformer::includeFeatured(): CollectionResource`
     "data" => [

      [
        "id" => 123,
        "type" => "article",
          ...
        "topic" => [
          // loaded in `ArticleTransformer::includeTopic(): ItemResource`
          "id" => 234,
          "title" => "Content API",
          "relatedArticles" => [ 3, 5, 10 ],
        ]
      ],

      ...

      [
        "id" => 567,
        "type" => "newsItem",
         ...
        "event" => [
           // loaded in `NewsItemTransformer::includeEvent(): ItemResource`
          "id" => 789,
          "title" => "Introduction to GraphQL", 
          "startDate" => "2019-05-22T18h30",
          "endDate" => "2019-05-22T20h00",
          "location" => "London"
        ]
     ]
  ]
]
```

As far as I know, I need to pass in a single transformer class when creating a new collection resource in `LandingPage::includeFeatured()`. How do I tell element-api / fractal to use a different transformer for featured article entries than for featured newsItem entries?

I tried to use a "man in the middle" transformer, which would then delegate by picking/instanciating a custom transformer for each entry, but then how do I pass the include names, and how do I make sure nested includes still work?

This seems to be more related to Fractal than to Craft, but if some-one who knows his way around the Craft Element API plugin implementation can help, that'd be great! Many thanks :)